# Where condition when two column is not false same time

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, boolean, query-builder

For example i have 2 column. 
status --> boolean
allowed --> boolean

I am trying to get `1,0` - `0,1` - `1,1`
How can i get collection when status is false and allowed is false.

```
$data = Data::whereNot('allowed', false)->whereNot('status', false)->get();
```

is return 1,1 condition as expected. Can we make this query in one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get one of them is true, or both are true:

```php
$data = Data::where('allowed', true)->orWhere('status', true)->get();
```